# Is the diagonal measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have $X=Y=[0,1]$, $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and $\nu$ the counting measure on $[0,1]$. Show that the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is $\lambda\times\nu$-measurable.

I thought that maybe I could show that $\Delta^c$ is measurable, by taking $\Delta^c=\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_n$, with all the $A_n$ (measurable) rectangles, but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume here you are using the completed product measure (certain authors do not). If so, one way to see this is to show that it has outer measure zero by covering it with small rectangles.

Comment: @Ian: Surely any non-trivial rectangle has infinite measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta_n = \cup_{k=0}^{n-1} [{k \over n}, {k+1 \over n}]^2 $. Then $\Delta = \cap_n \Delta_n$. Each $[{k \over n}, {k+1 \over n}]^2$ is $\lambda \times \nu$ measurable.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that $(\lambda\times \nu)^*(\Delta)=\infty$ (as all the rectangles have infinite measure)?

Comment: Yes, assuming you mean the outer measure.

Comment: (Note that there can be more than one product measure in this case.)

Comment: More than one product measure? You mean that the outer measure of $\Delta$ can assume multiple values?

Comment: No, the outer measure defines one measure, of course. But there are other measures that are product measures (basically satisfying $(\lambda \times \nu) (A \times B) = \lambda(A) \nu(B)$). If the underlying spaces are $\sigma$-finite, the product measure is unique, but this is not the case here.